# Tracking Unintended Row Changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a custom eCommerce web site, using third-party web services, that is processing dues payments for our members. Twice in the last day a specific data row for 50,000 users is having two of the dollar amount columns change to $0 for all 50,000 rows. Just those two columns are updated, nothing else in the row changes.

We have reviewed our coding and SPs and can find nothing that would update those rows.

I have approximate times that the events occurred, how would I find out what was running on the SQL Server at the time that could have made the change? I have looked through the Windows Event and SQL Server logs and do not see anything out of the ordinary. So I'm assuming that the update is coming from an authorized user.

I realize I may not be able to see the past if I don't have logging set up properly. The SQL Server (12.0.5557.0) is very vanilla configuration. But any clue to looking at history or setting up for future logging would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see naively written triggers do stuff like this quite a bit. You may want to look at `SELECT * FROM sys.triggers AS t` in the database this occurs in.

Answer (score 0):

Brian,

Unfortunately the Windows event log and SQL log will not provide that information.

Fortunately there are several ways to audit a such activity. SQLShack has a good explanation on the various techniques and 3rd party tools

https://www.sqlshack.com/various-techniques-to-audit-sql-server-databases/

I had a similar situation at my work where I need to track some unintentional updates to a table that seemed to happen a couple of times a week.

I decided to use out of the box SQL Server auditing features. I was able to track down who, where and when certain DML changes were occuring..

You need to first setup a server audit then create a database audit..

You can tailor your database audit to "update" statements on your specific table.. Limiting the audit to your table and "update" statements will limit the amount of auditing taking place.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification?view=sql-server-2017

You set up the server audit to log the activity to a file locally or somewhere on your network. Make sure the SQL Service account has write permissions to whatever location you choose.

You will have to use the function sys.fn_get_audit_file to read the audit file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

After you have solved the issue you can simply disable or delete the server and database audit.

Comment: Your links appear to cover the 2017 version of SQL Server - the OP is asking about 2014 - will your solution still work?

Comment: Sorry I sent the wrong links. The audit features are available in SQL 2014
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification?view=sql-server-2014

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create an audit table and log changes via an update trigger.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737723/log-record-changes-in-sql-server-in-an-audit-table for an example of how to set this up so that it captures metadata like who did the change and when, along with the old data values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database is in full recovery mode, and you have all the full / log backup files available, I would do the following

1. Restore the database on another server to the point of time when the updates have completed.
2. Rely on `fn_dblog()` to check the what happened.

You can refer https://sqlwithmanoj.com/tag/fn_dblog/ for `fn_dblog()` usage.

Good luck !

Edit:
To ensure you do not have any SP or trigger accidentally update the two columns, use the following query to find any potential candidates.

```
  use [your db name]
  select object_name(object_id), definition
  from sys.sql_modules
  where definition like '%update %col_1%'
  and definition like '%col_2%'
```

Replace `col_1` and `col_2` with your real column names, this will return you a list of SPs/triggers that may do the updates on the two columns.

You can write a similar query on msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps for [command] column and see whether there is a potential job step that update the two columns.

PS: If i understand correctly, the OP is asking how to find out what already happened before, **not** asking for how to audit the issue for future. But you can refer to other answers if you do want to set up the auditing mechanism.